# Angular2 nested template driven form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

This is just madness , looks like there is no way to have a form which one of it's inputs is in a child component .

I have read all the blogs and tutorials and everything , no way to work this out .

The problem is when a child component is going to have any kind of form directives ( ngModel , ngModelGroup or whatever ..) , it wont work.

***This is only a problem in template driven forms***

This is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/m0u1On?p=preview) :

```ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-form-component',
  template: ` 
  <fieldset ngModelGroup="address">
    <div>
      <label>Street:</label>
      <input type="text" name="street" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Zip:</label>
      <input type="text" name="zip" ngModel>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>City:</label>
      <input type="text" name="city" ngModel>
    </div>
  </fieldset>`
})

export class childFormComponent{


}

@Component({
  selector: 'form-component',
  directives:[childFormComponent],
  template: `
    <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(form.value)">
      <fieldset ngModelGroup="name">
        <div>
          <label>Firstname:</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstname" ngModel>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Lastname:</label>
          <input type="text" name="lastname" ngModel>
        </div>
      </fieldset>

      <child-form-component></child-form-component>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <pre>
      {{form.value | json}}
    </pre>

    <h4>Submitted</h4>
    <pre>    
      {{value | json }}
    </pre>
  `
})
export class FormComponent {

  value: any;

  submit(form) {
    this.value = form; 
  }
}
```

Comment: See also https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475

Answer (score 98):

One simple solution is to provide `ControlContainer` in `viewProviders` array of your child component like:

```typescript
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 ...,
 viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ua5xcz?file=app/address.component.ts)**

Read also this article that explains why it's working.

- [Angular: Nested template driven form](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475)

**Update**

If you're looking for **nested model driven form** then here is the similar approach:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form-child',
  template: `<input formControlName="age">`,
  viewProviders: [
    {
      provide: ControlContainer,
      useExisting: FormGroupDirective
    }
  ]
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(private parent: FormGroupDirective) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.parent.form.addControl('age', new FormControl('', Validators.required))
  }
}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/RIe5KPUyIhlQnVjIlS76?open=app%2Fchild.component.ts)**

### Update 2

If you don't know exactly which type of `ControlContainer` wraps your custom component(for example your controls is inside FormArray directive) then just use common version:

```typescript
import { SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
 ...,
 viewProviders: [{
   provide: ControlContainer,
   useFactory: (container: ControlContainer) => container,
   deps: [[new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]],
 }]
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/C0iufzjZl2GzLL7fcpaD)**

Comment: Holy shit. I've been waiting FOREVER for this feature! Thanks for the post.

Comment: This isn't working for me - I getting a "No provider for NgForm!".  I suspect it's because our custom form control has a <ng-content> where the various controls are then inserted.  Any idea what the work-around for this might be?

Comment: @JakeShakesworth Please create plunker or stackblitz example to reproduce

Comment: In the nested template driven form approach, everything is working fine, But how to get the parent form object in child component?

Comment: @Nimishgoel `this.parent.form` refers to parent FormGroup in my last example

Comment: Is there any way, I can get the child component form controls in the child component as well? I need to show the validation error message in the child component form input fields.

Comment: SO simple, just one line... `viewProviders: [{provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm}]` :)

Comment: yurzui, coming back after some time on a component using your implementation and getting @JakeShakesworth issue. I'm investigating.

Comment: nice solution, but how can I test it? now my unit-tests fail!

Comment: @yurzui - can you help with two-level hierarchy. for ex. check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xpv7n3 How can we get zip under address? Thanks!

Comment: @ManishJain You need to use NgModelGroup for viewProviders in zip component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qse4xu?file=app/zip.component.ts or more abstract way by providing ControlContainer as I described in Update2 https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rbkufw?file=app/zip.component.ts. Also if you don't want to have additional property like `{ zip: { zip: '' }}` then remove `<fieldset ngModelGroup="zip">` wrapper from your zip component https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixlr45?file=app/zip.component.ts

Comment: You are a rockstar @yurzui, thank you!!! add me to your top fan list ;)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Was stuck on this same issue for a couple hours until I came across this post. This seems to be the only post that addresses this issue too

Comment: If the component is also used outside forms, then you can add `new Optional()` to the deps array: `deps: [[new Optional(), new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]]`.

Comment: Update 2 solution works great but it breaks updateOn: 'blur' validation, for some reason it still triggers validators on every change in the input. Is that a bug? Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Is it possible to register a FormGroup on a NgForm like this? I tried it but it looks like the FormGroup in the child  really expects another FormGroup in the parent.

Answer (score 22):

Reading through a bunch of related github issues [[1]](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11174) [[2]](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9281), I haven't found a straightforward way to make angular add a child `Component`'s controls to a parent `ngForm` (some people also call them nested forms, nested inputs or complex controls).

So what I'm going to show here is a workaround that *works for me*, using separate `ngForm` directives for parents and childs. It's not perfect, but it gets me close enough that I stopped there.

I declare my `childFormComponent` with an `ngForm` directive (i.e. it's **not** a html form tag, only the directive):

```
<fieldset ngForm="addressFieldsForm" #addressFieldsForm="ngForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.email" name="email" #email="ngModel" required placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  ...
```

The Component then exposes the `addressFieldsForm` as a property, and also exports itself as a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mst-address-fields',
  templateUrl: './address-fields.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-fields.component.scss'],
  exportAs: 'mstAddressFields'
})
export class AddressFieldsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('addressFieldsForm') public form: NgForm;
  ....
```

The parent form can then use the child form component like this:

```
  <form (ngSubmit)="saveAddress()" #ngFormAddress="ngForm" action="#">
    <fieldset>
      <mst-address-fields [model]="model" #addressFields="mstAddressFields"></mst-address-fields>
      <div class="form-group form-buttons">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!ngFormAddress.valid || !addressFields.form.valid">Save</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

Note that the submit button explicitly checks valid state on both the `ngFormAddress` and the `addressFields` form. That way I can at least sensibly compose complex forms, even though it has some boilerplate.

Comment: Johannes Rudolph for president. You saved my day :) Thanks!

Comment: Based on your answer, I found a way so child components can auto-wire themselves into a shared form serice: https://gist.github.com/jehugaleahsa/c40fb64d8613cfad8f1e1faa4c2a7e33

Comment: @TravisParks you should add your complete Solution as a new answer on this post its working great! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 13):

Another possible workaround:

```js
@Directive({
    selector: '[provide-parent-form]',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: ControlContainer,
            useFactory: function (form: NgForm) {
                return form;
            },
            deps: [NgForm]
        }
    ]
})
export class ProvideParentForm {}
```

Just place this directive in a child component somewhere at the top of nodes hierarchy (before any ngModel).

**How it works**: NgModel [qualifies](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/71f5b73296708014b740fb5dd0145c0599de7a19/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_model.ts#L126) parent form's dependency lookup with @Host(). So a form from a parent component is not visible to NgModel in a child component. But we can inject and provide it inside a child component using the code demonstrated above.

Comment: Excellent solution! You should write a blog post about this.

Comment: I'd love a blog post to go into depth more on this

Comment: @artem it's not working in my sample plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/VSUzQtrtEmXSIEPzAjXb Do you know why?

Comment: @MartinoBordin, I'm not sure what is not working for you. I've checked it a few seconds ago - if I clear any child input I'm getting "Valid: false"

Comment: @ArtemAndreev yes, but if you type a char into one child input (while the others are still empty and in error) the form would be "Valid:true"

Comment: @MartinoBordin, ok, that's because you have the same name for all child-inputs. You need to have something like ```name="childInput-{{rowNumber}}"``` instead of ```name="childInput"```

Comment: @ArtemAndreev I tried what you suggested and it is almost working: https://plnkr.co/edit/WzFsoFbWRgIAu8Nv3Lst If you delete for example the first item ('Apple) and then you add another child, the second binding will be wrong

Comment: Is important to note that the injected form can be accessed in the child component by declaring the form property in the constructor, by using public form: NgForm.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a solution using a directive and service. Once you add those to your module, the only other code change you need to make are at the form level in the templates. This works with dynamically added form fields and AOT.  It also supports multiple unrelated forms on a page. Here's the plunker:  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5584n3S3CakudvdyImpP?p=preview).

It uses this directive:

```js
import { Directive, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { NestedFormService } from './nested-form.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[nestedForm]',
    exportAs: 'nestedForm'   
})
export class NestedFormDirective {    
    @Input('nestedForm') ngForm: NgForm;
    @Input() nestedGroup: string;
       
    public get valid() {
        return this.formService.isValid(this.nestedGroup);
    }

    public get dirty() {
        return this.formService.isDirty(this.nestedGroup);
    }

    public get touched() {
        return this.formService.isTouched(this.nestedGroup);
    }
    
    constructor(      
        private formService: NestedFormService
    ) { 
        
    }

    ngOnInit() {   
        this.formService.register(this.ngForm, this.nestedGroup);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.formService.unregister(this.ngForm, this.nestedGroup);
    } 

    reset() {
        this.formService.reset(this.nestedGroup);
    }
}
```

And this service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Injectable()
export class NestedFormService {

    _groups: { [key: string] : NgForm[] } = {};
      
    register(form: NgForm, group: string = null) {           
        if (form) {
            group = this._getGroupName(group);
            let forms = this._getGroup(group);        
            if (forms.indexOf(form) === -1) {
                forms.push(form);
                this._groups[group] = forms;
            }
        }
    }

    unregister(form: NgForm, group: string = null) {        
        if (form) {
            group = this._getGroupName(group);
            let forms = this._getGroup(group);
            let i = forms.indexOf(form);
            if (i > -1) {
                forms.splice(i, 1);
                this._groups[group] = forms;
            }
        }
    }

    isValid(group: string = null) : boolean {   
        group = this._getGroupName(group);         
        let forms = this._getGroup(group);
       
        for(let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            if (forms[i].invalid)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    } 

    isDirty(group: string = null) : boolean {   
        group = this._getGroupName(group);         
        let forms = this._getGroup(group);
       
        for(let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            if (forms[i].dirty)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 

    isTouched(group: string = null) : boolean {   
        group = this._getGroupName(group);         
        let forms = this._getGroup(group);
       
        for(let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            if (forms[i].touched)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 

    reset(group: string = null) {
        group = this._getGroupName(group);         
        let forms = this._getGroup(group);
       
        for(let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
            forms[i].onReset();
        }
    }

    _getGroupName(name: string) : string {
        return name || '_default';
    }

    _getGroup(name: string) : NgForm[] {        
        return this._groups[name] || [];
    }          
}
```

To use the directive in a parent component with a form:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './person.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'parent-form',
    template: `  
        <div class="parent-box">

            <!--
            ngForm                        Declare Angular Form directive
            #theForm="ngForm"             Assign the Angular form to a variable that can be used in the template
            [nestedForm]="theForm"        Declare the NestedForm directive and pass in the Angular form variable as an argument
            #myForm="nestedForm"          Assign the NestedForm directive to a variable that can be used in the template
            [nestedGroup]="model.group"   Pass a group name to the NestedForm directive so you can have multiple forms on the same page (optional).
            -->

            <form 
                ngForm                  
                #theForm="ngForm" 
                [nestedForm]="theForm"
                #myForm="nestedForm" 
                [nestedGroup]="model.group">        

                <h3>Parent Component</h3> 
                <div class="pad-bottom">
                    <span *ngIf="myForm.valid" class="label label-success">Valid</span>
                    <span *ngIf="!myForm.valid" class="label label-danger">Not Valid</span>
                    <span *ngIf="myForm.dirty" class="label label-warning">Dirty</span>    
                    <span *ngIf="myForm.touched" class="label label-info">Touched</span>    
                </div> 

                <div class="form-group" [class.hasError]="firstName.invalid">
                    <label>First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" [(ngModel)]="model.firstName" #firstName="ngModel" class="form-control" required />
                </div>

                <child-form [model]="model"></child-form>
               
                <div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="myForm.reset()">Reset</button>
                </div>
            </form>   
        </div>
    `
})
export class ParentForm {   
    
    model = new Person();
   
}
```

Then in a child component:

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Person } from './person.model';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-form',
    template: `  
        <div ngForm #theForm="ngForm" [nestedForm]="theForm" [nestedGroup]="model.group" class="child-box">
            <h3>Child Component</h3>
            <div class="form-group" [class.hasError]="lastName.invalid">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" [(ngModel)]="model.lastName" #lastName="ngModel" class="form-control" required />
            </div>
        </div>  
    `
})
export class ChildForm {    
    @Input() model: Person;
      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From official [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModelGroup-directive.html): 
`This directive can only be used as a child of NgForm.`

So I think you can try to wrap your child component in different `ngForm`, and expect in parent component result `@Output` of child component. Let me know if you need more clarification.

**UPDATE:**
Here is [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nEkNxrb4n8XuaDeRUM6f?p=preview) with some changes, I converted child form to model driven, because there is no way to listen on form driven form for updated before it will be submited.

Comment: Components are isolated in ng2, so that should answered for first sentence . Attaching plunker

Comment: You're using reactive way of defining the controls , where as the whole question is about template driven forms.

Comment: I have answered your question, why it is not working - because your child component have no ngForm.

Comment: Your answer is related to reactive forms and here is about template driven. any solution?

Answer (score 1):

With ~100 controls in dynamic forms, the implicit inclusion of controls may make you a template-driven juggernaut. The following will apply [yurzui's miracle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46748943/392895) everywhere.

```
export const containerFactory = (container: ControlContainer) => container;

export const controlContainerProvider = [{
  provide: ControlContainer,
  deps: [[new Optional(), new SkipSelf(), ControlContainer]],
  useFactory: containerFactory
}]

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel]',
  providers: [controlContainerProvider]
})
export class ControlContainerDirective { }
```

Provide controlContainerProvider to components with NgModelGroup.

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6etpnp)

Forms require controls to set a name attribute by default. Use the following directive to remove this requirement, and include controls only when a name attribute is set.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostBinding, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel]:not([name]):not([ngModelOptions])',
  providers: [{
    provide: ControlContainer,
    useValue: null
  }]
})
export class StandaloneDirective implements OnInit { }
```

[StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d4hy3d)