# Angular 2: Form containing child component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have component which has a form and some child components within the form. The child components are created using `*ngFor` and each child contains `input` elements. Angular2 compiler is giving errors like [formGroup] is not defined.

Is this implementation a correct?

Parent Component:

```html
<section class="data-body">
        <form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" novalidate>
            <app-checkout-product-view *ngFor="let item of checkoutData.products" [_product]="item" formGroupName="products"></app-checkout-product-view>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Nominee:</label>
                    <select required [(ngModel)]="checkoutData.selectedNominee" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                        <option *ngFor="let nominee of checkoutData.nomineeList" [value]="nominee">{{nominee}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label>Bank Account:</label>
                    <select [(ngModel)]="checkoutData.selectedBank" required [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                        <option *ngFor="let bank of checkoutData.bankList" [value]="bank">{{bank}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
```

Child Component: `app-checkout-product-view`

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <md-input required [(ngModel)]="product.investmentAmount 
                  formControlName="investmentAmount">
            <span md-prefix>&#x20B9;</span><!--Rupee icon-->
        </md-input>
    </div>
</div>
```

P.S. : All the imports are fine so I am pretty sure that no import errors here

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This behavior is expected. Angular forms are not automatically registered when inside nested component. However you can workaround this by providing the outer FormGroup to the child component. And inside the child component wrap the template inside that same group. Here is how this might look:

/outer component code - it contains the form/

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="reactiveFormGroup">
      <input formControlName="foo" />
      <my-comp **[group]="reactiveFormGroup"**></my-comp>
    </form>

    form value: {{ reactiveFormGroup.value | json }}
  `
})
export class AppComponent { 
  reactiveFormGroup = new FormGroup({
    foo: new FormControl('default foo'),
    bar: new FormControl('default bar')
  });
}
```

/child component code, i.e my-comp/

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="group">
      <input   [formControlName]="'bar'" />
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent { 
  @Input() group: FormGroup;
}
```

Comment: There is a recent blog post that goes though an example of this as well. You can find it here: https://toddmotto.com/component-architecture-reactive-forms-angular

Comment: hi @DeborahK is the answer by rusev above still the best answer for Angular 8 in year 2019? Thanks

Comment: Hey @TomBook I suspect that it is still the case and thank you. At the time of writing this post I was already a several months into development of UI library based on Angular and I have to say that I hit a ton of "corner" cases. At that time there wasn't many posts on the subject, so when I had time I decided to give back to the community. These days I don't use Angular anymore.

Comment: hi @rusev what do you use these days for new framework? I keep hearing "I don't use Angular anymore"  Do you utilize React or Vue?

Comment: Mostly React, but I also experiment with Elm and Svelte.

Comment: For others who get here, this won't work for template driven forms but this will: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46748943/1316683

Comment: Updated link to the blog post mentioned in comments here: https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/component-architecture-reactive-forms-angular

Answer (score 3):

You're saying the imports are fine but the errors you're getting suggest that they probably are not.

`[formGroup] is not defined` errors are usually caused by a missing
`import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'` inside the module where your component is declared.

Besides that, you should not use `[(ngModel)]` inside model-driven forms but instead rely on `[formGroup]` and `formControlName`.

Comment: these are my imports `import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";`

Comment: Secondly is it okay to have child components within the form?

Comment: These are the imports you need inside your component class. But that component must be declared inside a module. Inside that module you need to register _**ReactiveFormsModule**_ as an import inside the `imports: []` array.

Comment: Module level imports are also fine, the whole thing is working in other component which has no child components in the form

Comment: Perhaps I could be of more help if you posted your _component.ts_ and _module.ts_ files.