# Angular form undefined

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am trying to put form validation but I am getting form element is undefined. If I remove app-root element from index.html, it starts working as per expectation.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>NKZ Technologies</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script type="script" src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"> 
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="myForm">
          Valid = {{myForm.$valid}}
        ̶<̶/̶f̶o̶r̶m̶>̶
         <app-root></app-root>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Ankit

---

@georgeawg your suggestion works for me but only in `index.html`.

Now `app-root` element renders `app.component`. I am having same form `undefine` issue in app.component.html.

```
<div id="main-content">
  <form name="test">
      a = {{test.$valid}} 
  </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: code sample with the error?

Comment: @felixmosh. Sorry, I forgot to add code. Now I have updated. myForm is invalid.

Comment: Are using `AngularJS` or `Angular (2>)`?

Comment: @felixmosh. I am using angular 2.

Comment: The code has an `ng-app` directive and loads `angular/angular.js`. NOT cool if you are asking an angular2 question. Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 nested forms with child components and validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408188/angular-2-nested-forms-with-child-components-and-validation).

Answer (score 0):

Include the `<app-root>` component in the `<form>` element:

```
<body>
  <form name="myForm">
    Valid = {{myForm.$valid}}
  ̶<̶/̶f̶o̶r̶m̶>̶
    <app-root></app-root>
  </form>
</body>
```

The input elements inside the `<app-root>` component can only register with the form controller if it encloses those elements.

---

Also, remember to import the FormsModule:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CoreModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I am using angular 2. your suggestion works for me but only in index.html. Now app-root element renders app.component. I am having same form undefine issue in app.component.html. 

<div id="main-content">

    <form name="test">
        a = {{test.$valid}}
    </form>

</div>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 nested forms with child components and validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44408188/angular-2-nested-forms-with-child-components-and-validation)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Below trick wors for me.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
```

Thanks,