# angular component with multiple inputs and validation (required)

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-validation

I want to create a custom component with multiple input controlls which I can use in other components forms including the validation. The only examples I could find show how to create a simple component with ONE input and a custom validator. But I was not possible to create a component with two or more inputs like

```
@Component({
    selector: 'stationDefaultProperties',
    template: '<div><span>Name:</span>
      <input [(ngModel)]="values.Name" (change)="onChanges()" name="name"  required maxlength="200" minlength="2" type="text">
      <span>Beschreibung:</span>
      <textarea [(ngModel)]="values.Beschreibung" name="beschreibung" minlength="4" type="text" rows="3"></textarea></div>',
    providers: [
        {
            provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
            useExisting: forwardRef(() => StationDefaultPropertiesComponent),
            multi: true
        }
    ]
})
export class StationDefaultPropertiesComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
    @ViewChild('cF') public userFrm: NgForm;

    public values: my.Container.IStationDefaultProperties = {
        Aktiv: false,
        Beschreibung: "",
        Name: "",
        StationId: 0
    };

    constructor() { }

    public writeValue(value: my.Container.IStationDefaultProperties): void {
        if (value) {
            this.values = value;
            console.log(value);
        }
    }

    public onChanges(): void {
        this.propagateChange(this.values);
    }

    public registerOnChange(fn): void {
        this.propagateChange = fn;
    }

    public registerOnTouched(fn): void { }

    // the method set in registerOnChange to emit changes back to the form
    private propagateChange = (_: any) => { };
}
```

I am using the "ControlValueAccessor" so that I can call my component with "[(ngModel)]"

```
<form #f="ngForm" name="f" novalidate>
<stationDefaultProperties name="stdProperties" [(ngModel)]="viewModel && viewModel.DefaultProperties"></stationDefaultProperties>
 {{f.valid}} => is ALLWAYS TRUE
</form>
```

but the problem is I don't know how to implement the required validator for only one of my inputs and a minlength validator for both of them. The form is allways valid on start, but it shouldn't because there is no value in the required field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a great Solution in this post

[Angular2 nested template driven form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form)

and there is a link to a gist which contains a detailed information about the solution

https://gist.github.com/jehugaleahsa/c40fb64d8613cfad8f1e1faa4c2a7e33

The solution don't uses the "ControlValueAccessor" and I think its a really cool solution for my kind of problem, with multiple inputs in a custom component.