# Form in form. Can there be inheritance of form controls?

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I have two components: ParentComponent and ChildComponent:

**parent.component.ts**

```
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form)" novalidate>
     <input type="text" name="firstControl" [(ngModel)]="firstControl" />
     <input type="text" name="secondControl" [(ngModel)]="secondControl" />
     <child-component>
</form>
{{form.value | json}}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
<input type="text" name="thirdControl" [(ngModel)]="thirdControl" />
<input type="text" name="fourthControl" [(ngModel)]="fourthControl" />
```

Now, `{{form.value | json}}` returns `{ "firstControl": "", "secondControl": "" }` and it's clear. My question is: Is there a way to form enherit form controls from child component? What is the correct way to get `{ "firstControl": "", "secondControl": "", "thirdControl": "", "fourthControl": "" }` for ParentComponent? Is it possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:**

Indeed there is an easier way:

```
import { FormsModule, ControlContainer, NgForm, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  ...
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class ChildComponent {}
```

See also

- [Angular2 nested template driven form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form/46748943#46748943)

**Previous version:**

I would say it's possible. For example you could add the following code to your

**child.component.ts**

```
import { NgForm, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  template: `
      <input type="text" name="thirdControl" [(ngModel)]="thirdControl" />
      <input type="text" name="fourthControl" [(ngModel)]="fourthControl" />
    `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @ViewChildren(NgModel) ngModels: QueryList<NgModel>;

  constructor(@Optional() private ngForm: NgForm) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.ngForm) {
      this.ngModels.forEach(model => this.ngForm.addControl(model));
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/l9WARkj3AenHqGtkxHrY?p=preview)**

Angular DI system gives us the opportunity to get reference to parent `NgForm` instance because angular dependency resolution algorithm starts with current node and goes up through tree of elements. In my example we can imagine the follwing tree

```
              @NgModule providers
                    |
                  my-app
                    |
                   form
          /         |       \
   input[text] input[text] child-component
```

So when we are requiring `NgForm` token angular will search it in the next order

```
child-component
     ||
     \/
    form
     ||
     \/
   my-app
     ||
     \/
  @NgModule
```

On form element `NgForm` directive is placed so when can get it. Also we can get any token that was declared on `NgForm` directive within `providers` array. And this rule applies to any node.

See also [Angular 2 - How does ng-bootstrap provide the NgbRadioGroup and NgbButtonLabel to their NgbRadio directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332859/angular-2-how-does-ng-bootstrap-provide-the-ngbradiogroup-and-ngbbuttonlabel-t)

Then i just added child `NgModel` directives manually to `NgForm` so they should work together.

Comment: What a great post!

Comment: Perfect explanation. Thanks a lot, dude.

Comment: can you also show a test? really struggling with the test

Comment: How can I access NgForm in the HTML (using the easier way)?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has two kinds of forms, Template Driven and Reactive. What you want to do isn't possible with Template Driven forms, you'll need to look into  [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

In general it works by creating a form object in the component, and using it in the template. Angular says this is actually more flexible and easier to test, but I think the syntax is a lot harder to wrap your head around.

You'll want this in your parent component:

```
  myForm: FormGroup; 

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { // <--- inject FormBuilder
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      firstControl: '',
      secondControl: '',
      thirdControl: '',
      fourthControl: ''
    });
  }
```

Your parent template would look something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate>
<input type="text"formControlName="firstControl" />
     <input type="text" formControlName="secondControl" />
     <child-component [parentFormGroup]="myForm">
</form>
```

And your child will accept the form group as an input, and the template will look something like this:

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="parentFormGroup">
  <input type="text" formControlName="thirdControl" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="fourthControl" />
</div>
```