# How to test Component having a constructor with child component object in it - in Angular2 (Jasmine -Karma)

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am writing a test cases using Jasmine Karma in Angular 2 component which having constructor. In this constructor I am passing other component object as a parameter. When trying to access methods of other component are getting undefined.

**1. TestComponent**

```
@Component({
    template: `<div></div>`
})
class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(public otherComponent: OtherComponent) {}
    ngOnInit() {}
    callMyFunction() {
        this.otherComponent.otherFunction();
    }
}
```

**2. OtherComponent**

```
@Component({
    selector: "other-component",
    template: `<div></div>`
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {}
    public otherFunction(): void {
        console.log('test function called');
    }
}
```

**3. Test Case**

```
describe("TestComponent", () => {

    let comp: TestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture < TestComponent > ;
    let de: DebugElement;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule],
            declarations: [TestComponent, OtherComponent],
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        de = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    fit("Should call otherFunction of OtherComponent.", () => {
        spyOn(comp.otherComponent, "otherFunction").and.callThrough();
        comp.callMyFunction();
        expect(comp.otherComponent.otherFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Are you getting `Error: No provider for OtherComponent!`?

Comment: Yes....getting error No provider for OtherComponent

Comment: OtherComponent template should contain TestComponent definition

Comment: Can you elaborate more or how to add TestComponent definition in OtherComponent template

Comment: TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent) creates only TestComponent instance it doesn't have any parent components. But dependency injection system requires parent component or we can provide it manually

Comment: How to inject other component object and where to inject in describe or in it

Comment: It won't create OtherComponent because angular doesn't know how to get it: OtherComponent hasn't any providers and it's root component

Comment: You can either add it to providers array or create OtherComponent with template that contains TestComponent

Comment: How i can add providers in Other component object

Comment: Providers of your module https://plnkr.co/edit/06QcOMdIuVgp3N8YGDEY?p=preview or providers of TestComponent

Comment: How are they connected in your real application?

Comment: Thank you @yurzui got it... ....

Comment: We usually write test where child component is part of parent like `@Component({
  selector: "other-component",
  template: `<test-comp></test-comp>`
})
export class OtherComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(TestComponent) testComponent;` Then we can create instance of OtherComponent and get child through @ViewChild. In this case we do not need add component in providers array

Comment: Read this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332859/angular-2-how-does-ng-bootstrap-provide-the-ngbradiogroup-and-ngbbuttonlabel-t I am explaining there how angular DI system works in tree of elements