# No provider for NgForm error in dev mode using Angular 4.4.6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

**EDIT:** I've discovered what is causing the problem; I'm now looking for a solution as to how to cater for it.

*NOTE*: This issue is happening in dev mode (i.e. not prod, and not using aot)

I'm using the "Update" solution from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46324043/3164070

To solve an issue with an input in a child component that was not updating the valid flag on the form. It works in a fairly simple test project, however when moving it to our real project, it throws this error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for NgForm!
Error: No provider for NgForm!
    at ZoneAwareError (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:153804:33)
    at injectionError (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1378:90)
    at noProviderError (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1416:12)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2858:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2897:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2829:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2698:21)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:9701:25)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:10771:16)
    at resolveDep (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11259:45)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11102:20)
    at resolveDep (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11238:56)
    at createClass (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11129:32)
    at createDirectiveInstance (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:10960:37)
    at createViewNodes (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12401:53)
    at ZoneAwareError (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:153804:33)
    at injectionError (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1378:90)
    at noProviderError (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:1416:12)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2858:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2897:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2829:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:2698:21)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:9701:25)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:10771:16)
    at resolveDep (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11259:45)
    at _createProviderInstance (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11102:20)
    at resolveDep (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11238:56)
    at createClass (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:11129:32)
    at createDirectiveInstance (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:10960:37)
    at createViewNodes (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12401:53)
    at resolvePromise (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:153599:31) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:153570:17) [angular]
    at http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:153647:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:4090:33) [angular]
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:153284:36) [angular]
    at Zone.runTask (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:153052:47) [<root> => angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://192.168.2.34:4200/vendor.bundle.js:153480:35) [<root>]
    at <anonymous> [<root>]
```

The problem is that the same component can be used without being on a form, so there is no provider for NgForm.

Is there some way of using the viewProviders member dynamically in the case where there is no form?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yeah, you can provide it as `null` in case if there is no parent `NgForm` provider:

```
export function controlContainerFactory(controlContainer?: ControlContainer) {
  return controlContainer;
}

...

viewProviders: [ 
  { 
    provide: ControlContainer, 
    useFactory: controlContainerFactory, 
    deps: [[new Optional(), NgForm]] 
             ^^^^^^^^^^
          should do the trick
  } 
]
```

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ee2vhj?file=app/child.component.ts)**