# Angular2/4 - How can I add input fields from a TemplateRef into form inside a component?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components, ng-template

I have this component with this template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'form-component',
    template:`
        <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="formComponentSubmit(form)">
            <ng-container #tmlContainer></ng-container>
            <button type="submit">Component form submit</button>
        </form>`
})
export class FormComponent implements OnInit{
    @ViewChild('tmlContainer', {read: ViewContainerRef}) tmlContainer;
    @Input() templateIn: TemplateRef<any>;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.tmlContainer.insert(this.templateIn.createEmbeddedView(null));
    }

    formComponentSubmit(form) {
        console.log('Component', form)
    }
}
```

I need to know how can I get the input fields added into the TemplateRef and add it to my form.

//edit
The input fields must exist only in the form of inside the component and not on the form that is in the main app.

You can check the example in this link: https://plnkr.co/edit/cWWxRUlMfR6ecNbga8Y7?p=preview

Comment: Have you search on Google? https://blogs.ibs.com/2016/09/23/angular-2-templateref-usage/
Is it what you need?

Comment: Here's your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849570/cloned-elements-cannot-be-submitted-in-angular4/46863758?noredirect=1

Comment: @KeyMaker00 Yes, I've googled it. The link you provided just teach how to use the ng-template and it's already working. The problem is about adding the input fields that this template has into my form.

Comment: @yurzui Thanks! I'll try to implement the second case you said because the first one I can't use because the input fields must not be part of the form in the main application.

Comment: I've forgotten to say that the input fields added in the template could not be added to the form in the main app.

Comment: did u manage to solve it? @Rhino

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've tried a lot of things but no one really works so I had to give up.