# Angular 4 Template Driven nested form validation?

Tags: angular

I have 2 components, a parent component and a child component.  The parent component contains the following:

```
   <form (ngSubmit)="saveWebsite();" #adminForm="ngForm">

         <input type="text" name="WebName" [(ngModel)]="milestone.WebName" class="form-control" required/>

          <app-documents [documents]="caseData.CaseWebsiteDocuments" [caseId]="caseId" (fileEvent)="showToast($event)"
          (documentsEvent)="documentsEvent($event)"></app-documents>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" *ngIf="caseId">Save</button>
    </form>
```

The child component contains the following:

```
<input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="doc.FriendlyName" name="friendlyName" class="form-control" required/>
```

If I put all inputs in the parent component, the validation works for everything.  I am trying to check the dirty status.  Right now, if I make changes on the Parent, the dirty status is set to true, but if I make a change on the child, the dirty status does not change.  How can I get validation to work in template driven nested controls?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can provide `ControlContainer` on your child component like

```typescript
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-documents'
  ...,
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class AppDocumentsComponent {}
```

See also

- [Angular2 nested template driven form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form/46748943#46748943)

Comment: Wow, nice.  I did the following and just added ngModelGroup="documents" to a container div in my child component and it works.  Thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: How can I implement it in that case if I have more nested parts (forms) below the main form?

Comment: @Laszlo Can you provide an example on stackblitz?

Comment: I cannot provide an example, just think about it, you have the main form and it contains more Tab sheets, each tab sheet contains an individual component which has a lot of data entry fields. The submit button on the main form depends on all mandatory fields on various tab sheets.

Comment: @Laszlo If you have more nested forms then you probably want to use ngModelGroup. It also will work like in my solution but with only one difference: you need to use common version from the link in the question. Here's an example https://ng-run.com/edit/YLSx6OJVKYUbXQTsWOx2

Comment: Alexey, This is a good solution thank you!
Where can I learn in similar deep in Angular? Could you suggest me some courses?

Answer (score 1):

That alone didn't work for me I added `ngModel` in my input too. Without `ngModel` I think you can't validate your forms... whether it is a child or own component forms.

```
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-documents'
  ...,
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class AppDocumentsComponent {}
```

that works for me!!