# Angular child form field validation

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular2-forms

I have some existing code that's structured more or less like this:

```
<!-- my-form.html -->

<form ngNativeValidate>
    <my-other-component></my-other-component>
    <button mat-button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>


<!-- my-other-component.html -->

<input name='native-input' required />

<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select name='balls' required>
        <mat-option value='a'>a</mat-option>
        <mat-option value='b'>b</mat-option>
        <mat-option value='c'>c</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The problem: while the native input is validated correctly — the browser displays a "Please fill out this field." prompt upon submission when needed — an empty input to `balls` is happily accepted.

The `ngNativeValidate` behavior of showing generic/non-descriptive errors only upon submission is fine for now, and we don't have time to convert everything into an Angular form with custom validation messages, so that isn't an option. What I'm looking for is a way to switch from native validation to Angular validation with the least possible effort to maintain an acceptable UX — e.g. simply disabling the submit button until the form input is valid.

As per [angular.io/guide/form-validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation), I see that I can change `ngNativeValidate` to `#myForm='ngForm'` and add `[disabled]='myForm.invalid'` to the submit button. However, this validation is only applying to form fields directly within my-form.html, not the ones in `my-other-component`.

Documentation here is really sparse, so I'm not sure what to try next. Does anyone know if it's possible to configure `ngForm` to validate those descendant components' form fields?

Comment: Have you tried a custom validator?

Comment: I didn't see an obvious way to apply a custom validator to this problem based on my reading of the docs, but @yurzui came up with exactly what I was looking for below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use template driven form approach then you have to import `FormsModule` into your `@NgModule` and apply `NgModel` directive to all your controls

```
<input name='native-input' ngModel required />
                           ^^^^^^^
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select name='balls' ngModel required>
                             ^^^^^^^
    <mat-option value='a'>a</mat-option>
    <mat-option value='b'>b</mat-option>
    <mat-option value='c'>c</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Now your child component should be aware about parent form. In order to do that you need to provide `ControlContainer` token within `viewProviders` array:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-other-component',
  template: `
    ...
  `,
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class MyOtherComponent {
```

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/QLYHqIUmy3R7aVTsZc12?open=app%2Fmy-other.component.ts)**

See also:

- [Angular2 nested template driven form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form)

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! ng-run looks awesome btw.

Comment: How about if you want a reactive form instead of a template driven form? Could you provide an example of that please?

Comment: @olefrank It should be much differ from template driven. You can find examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form/46748943#46748943