# ngTemplateOutlet - Angular 5 nested template driven form

Tags: angular, nested-forms, angular-forms, ng-template

I have a ng-template which is being passed on from one of my component and i have a placeholder to accept the passed on ng-template onto my component as shown below in ngTemplateOutlet.

```
<div>
<form novalidate #myForm="ngForm">
  <ng-container>
    <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate">
    </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</form>
</div>

<!-- this template i am passing it from one of my other components -->
<ng-template #myTemplate>
  <input type="text" name="myInput" placeholder="Input"
    [(ngModel)]="inputModel" required/>
</ng-template>
```

The problem here is that my form('myForm') is ignoring the passed on ng-template eventhough it is marked as required. How can i make sure that my ngForm considers the passed on ng-template

Comment: already tried this fix but no luck - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form/45307924#45307924.
It will be better if i can handle it with a directive as provided in the above example itself

Comment: If you set the template outlet on the container? `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate"></ng-container>` Docs: [NgTemplateOutlet](https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet)

Comment: Tried it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Have you got a solution to this? I have the same issue

Comment: workaround below from saravana va works fine. This is probably a bug in Angular `ngTemplateOutlet`

Answer (score 10):

I found the answer and its very simple

Please move your  code... inside your form tag

```
<div>
   <form novalidate #myForm="ngForm">
      <ng-container>
          <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="myTemplate">
          </ng-template>
      </ng-container>
   </div>

      <!-- this template i am passing it from one of my other components -->
   <ng-template #myTemplate>
      <input type="text" name="myInput" placeholder="Input"
       [(ngModel)]="inputModel" required/>
     </ng-template>

  **</form>**
```

Comment: how about using with loop.?

Comment: I can confirm this works. This should be set as the correct answer.

Comment: You my hero of the day. Thanks!!