# How to get the template driven form data on parent component submit button

Tags: angular

I have a child component in which I have rendered the text `form input controls`. My submit button is rendered in parent component so while submitting the `form` I am getting the empty `data`.

**parent-component.html**

```
<form #f="ngForm" name="myForm">

<app-text [users]="users"></app-text>
<br><br>
<button (click)="save(f)">Save</button>
</form>
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  NgForm
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class ParentComponent  {

  public users = {
    'firstname' :'',
    'lastname' :''
    };

  public constructor()
  {

  }

  save(myForm:NgForm)
  {
    console.log(myForm.value);
  }
}
```

**child.component.ts** (TextComponent)

```
import { Component,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-text',
  templateUrl: './text.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './text.component.css' ]
})
export class TextComponent  {
  @Input() users:any;
}
```

**child.componet.html**

```
<label>Enter the First Name</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="users.firstname" name="firstname">

<label>Enter the Last Name</label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="users.lastname" name="lastname">
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA,CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TextComponent } from './text/text.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, TextComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  schemas:[CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here I am submitting my form with values and trying to fetch the data into save method of parent component but I am getting the empty data.

How can I achieve it? is there any other way to achieve it?

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You have to implement the [`ControlValueAccessor` interface](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor`) in order to make it work. Several guides exist online to make that.

Comment: Check this answer at this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46748943/7109092

Comment: ok i will check thanks.

Comment: @SandySanap you need to pass the `users` array to child component as two way binding `<app-text ([users])="users"></app-text>`, so that when it updates `users` object in child, it would be reflected back to parent

Comment: @dreamweiver i have passed array to child component as two way binding but i am getting ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'users' of undefined

Comment: @SandySanap, my mistake, can you update it as `<app-text [(users)]="users"></app-text>`

Comment: @dreamweiver still not working You can find the url of stackblitz.com here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejbehk

Comment: @SandySanap: I think it has something to do with the internal workings of `ngForm`, however, you can always check the value of firstName from `this.users.firstname` to get the entered value in the `save()` method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create components which are form component, I would strongly suggest you to use [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor).

This interface allows you to create component which can interact with both template driven or reactiv forms.