# Child controls not registered to parent form

Tags: angular

I have a form in a parent component and I want to register controls to it from a child component, but they don't appear in its list.

In my child component I have declared my control `#myVar="ngModel"` yet it doesn't register it on the parent form.

Simplified version of my code:

Parent:

`<form>
    <app-child></app-child>
</form>`

Child:

`<input #myInput="ngModel">
    <app-another-child [param]="myInput.control"></app-another-child>
</input>`

I'm not sure if I'm missing something - 1 week noob with angular :)

Comment: Maybe source code will be helpful.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a subform you need to specify this:

```
viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
```

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwg5rf) for working example.