# Angular2 ng-bootstrap nav with nested template-driven form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-forms, ng-bootstrap

I've been using the answers (and the article within) from [Angular2 nested template driven form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242219/angular2-nested-template-driven-form/46748943#46748943) to use child-nested form controls. Which is great until I try to use the child component within a [Ng-Bootstrap Nav component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/nav/overview), like so:

```
<ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs">
  <li ngbNavItem>
    <a ngbNavLink>One</a>
    <ng-template ngbNavContent>
      <nav-content-1></nav-content-1>
    </ng-template>
  </li>
</ul>

<form #form="ngForm">
  <div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav"></div>
</form>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'nav-content-1',
  template: `
    <h5>NavContent1</h5>
    <fieldset ngModelGroup>
      <label>Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastName" ngModel>
    </fieldset>
  `,
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm }],
})
export class NavContent1Component {}
```

At this point, I receive the error `NullInjectorError: No provider for NgForm`.

I'm just starting to get the hang of providers, so bear with me. But it seems like the component declared in `ngbNavContent` is not being registered as a child of the parent component, and thus is not able to find any of the what-would-be inherited providers.

If that is the case, is there a way to directly reference the `NgForm` in the parent component from the components in the nav content?

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngb-nav-forms?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav-basic.html)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngb-nav-forms-ccgu2u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnav-content-2.component.ts

Comment: Wow... okay, yeah that was it. I totally missed that. Thank you @yurzui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @yurzui for answering my question and showing me the folly of my ways. The form tag needed to be wrapped around the nav as well.

```
<form #form="ngForm">
  <ul ngbNav #nav="ngbNav" class="nav-tabs">
    <li ngbNavItem>
      <a ngbNavLink>One</a>
      <ng-template ngbNavContent>
        <nav-content-1></nav-content-1>
      </ng-template>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div [ngbNavOutlet]="nav"></div>
</form>
```